# Что такое Bundle savedInstanceState?

Tags: android

Методу  класса **Activity** onCreate() в качестве аргумента передается ссылка на объект класса Bundle :

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Но в самом теле метода **Bundle savedInstanceState** не реализуется.
Вопрос : куда
"дальше идет" ссылка на объект Bundle savedInstanceState после передачи методу в качестве аргумента, если в коде тела метода только одна строчка throw new RuntimeException("Stub!") ?

Comment: постарайтесь давать вопросам более конкретные заголовки, а не просто набор случайных слов по теме

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException("Stub!")` - это означает что вы смотрите не настоящий исходник класса, а заглушку для среды разработки. Вот `onCreate` `Activity` фреймворка: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/11ce7bf502a40bfbe6fb1d5dc37c307ab8c42797/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1452

Comment: @woesss Ого! Спасибо большое!! ))

Comment: посмотри тут , если бует не понятно просто загугли http://www.ohandroid.com/oncreate-bundle-savedinstancestate.html